# convert string to list in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to react and need some help. I have the below code

```
const payload = {
            mobileNumber: this.state.mobile,
            bookngDate: this.convertDayToDate(this.state.date),
            bookingTime: this.state.bookingTime,
            location: this.state.location,
            basebookedIndicator64Img: true,
            type:  this.state.court, // type is a list in the back-end
            courtName: this.state.courtName,
            courtId: this.state.courtId
        }
```

Type is a list in the backend, and thus want to convert this string to an array, please suggest

Comment: This is an `object`!

Comment: are there any delimiter in the string ? you can just spit it to make an array and render the list from it .

Comment: no, there are no delimiters in the string. I need a list with just a single object

Comment: Can you add the value of this.state.courtName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert the string into a list containing the string, you can change

```js
this.state.court,
```

to

```js
[this.state.court],
```

Comment: btw this is not specific to React, just JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` and  `map()` each item

```
const payload = {
            mobileNumber: this.state.mobile,
            bookngDate: this.convertDayToDate(this.state.date),
            bookingTime: this.state.bookingTime,
            location: this.state.location,
            basebookedIndicator64Img: true,
            type:  this.state.court, // type is a list in the back-end
            courtName: this.state.courtName,
            courtId: this.state.courtId
        }

const result = Object.keys(payload).map( (key)=> {
  // You can customize your array appearance
  return [key, payload[key]];
});

console.log(result);
```